# blacklist characters are not ignored by Tesseract OCR

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I am using Tessearct OCR for recognizing charcters of a image. But I want numeric characters to be ignored by OCR using

```
_tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_blacklist", "0123456789");
```

By this way OCR doesn't recognize numeric charactes but it provides me some others characters in place of them which I don't want.

As an example : There is an image which has text as **USD 12** , when I apply OCR on that image it provides me **USD fl**

as we can see above that OCR converted **12** to fl which I don't want . I want **12** to be ignored by OCR.

Is there any way to get result as **USD** not as  **USD fl**

Provide me any solution for that. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Can you just simply delete from the output text the numeric characters using Regex?

Comment: I want to improve results. Do you have any idea for that so that I could improve results?

Comment: Hello @nguyenq I want to discuss something related to tesseract sdk can you please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/25582/tesseract-ios?tab=general

Comment: By blacklisting the numeric, Tesseract is instructed to replace them with other, likely incorrect, letters -- making it difficult to remove the true numeric. So don't blacklist the numbers, let Tesseract detect them, and regex delete them from the output text. The recognition accuracy still depends largely on the quality of the input image, so preprocess it, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this comment for the method `SetVariable()` :

```
// For most variables, it is wise to set them before calling Init.
```

I had the same issue than you and moving the code before `Init` fixed it :

```
tess = new TessBaseAPI();    
tess->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", 
   "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
tess->SimpleInit([dataPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],  
   "eng", false);
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not what `tessedit_char_blacklist` is for. `tessedit_char_blacklist` guarantees that numbers will not be in the image. If you tell Tesseract incorrect information, you'll get bad results.

What you want instead is to post-process Tesseract's output. Let it output the correct OCR, and then just strip out the number characters.